# How to add a marker in a RadarChart using the MPAndroidChart library?

Tags: android, kotlin, charts, mpandroidchart, radar-chart

I am currently working on a project where I need to display a RadarChart using the MPAndroidChart library in my Android application. I have successfully plotted the data points on the chart, but now I would like to add a marker to indicate a specific point on the chart.

I have gone through the MPAndroidChart documentation and explored various resources, but I couldn't find any direct method or example for adding an animated marker to a RadarChart. I am specifically interested in having a marker that smoothly transitions between the data points, providing a visual animation effect. To better illustrate my requirement, I have created a simple mock-up of the desired result:

This is my Current Chart:

[image]

Requirement :

[image]

In the requirement image above, I have added a gray circle marker at a specific data point on the RadarChart. However, I'm unsure how to achieve this programmatically.

Could someone please guide me on how to add a marker to a RadarChart using the MPAndroidChart library? Any code snippets or references would be greatly appreciated.

This is the code I am using:

```kotlin
val markerView = CustomMarkerView(this@PersonalityDefaultStateActivity, R.layout.view_marker)
binding.radarChart.marker = markerView
```

```kotlin
class CustomMarkerView(context: Context, layoutResource: Int): MarkerView(context, layoutResource){
    private val tvContent: TextView = findViewById(R.id.tv_content)

    // This method will be called whenever a marker is drawn
    override fun refreshContent(entry: Entry?, highlight: Highlight?) {
        // Set the text content of the marker
        tvContent.text = entry!!.y.toString()
        super.refreshContent(entry, highlight)
    }

    // Set the position of the marker
    override fun getOffset(): MPPointF {
        return MPPointF((-(width / 2)).toFloat(), (-height).toFloat())
    }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_content"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_50sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="@drawable/marker_icon"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
   <!-- <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
        android:src="@drawable/marker_icon"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />-->

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```